# $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}=\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Riemann Hypothesis(RH) is equivalent to the statement "
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91280/is-this-sum-of-reciprocals-of-zeta-zeros-correct "$$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}=\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}$$ where $\rho$ denotes non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function.

**Question** Prove that RH is equivalent to $$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}=\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}$$
**Attempt**
Assume RH then $\Re(\rho)=\frac{1}{2}$ ,so $1-\rho=\overline{\rho}$
$$\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}=   \sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2} $$
Conversely, Assume,$$\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}=   \sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2} $$
$$\sum_\rho [\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}-\frac{1}{\rho\overline{\rho}}]=0$$
$$\sum_\rho \left(\frac{2\Re(\rho)-1}{\rho \bar{\rho}(1-\rho)}\right)=0$$
How to conclude that $$\Re(\rho)=\frac{1}{2}?$$

Comment: Note that if $\rho$ is a non-trivial zero then so is $1-\rho$. Thus $$
\sum\limits_\rho  {\frac{1}{{\rho (1 - \rho )}}}  = \sum\limits_\rho  {\frac{1}{\rho }}  + \sum\limits_\rho  {\frac{1}{{1 - \rho }}}  = \sum\limits_\rho  {\frac{1}{\rho }}  + \sum\limits_\rho  {\frac{1}{\rho }}  = 2\sum\limits_\rho  {\frac{1}{\rho }} .
$$ Now looking at the product formula and the Taylor series of the $\xi$ function, you can complete the proof (similarly to how Euler solved the Basel problem).

Comment: @Gary Sorry I could not follow. How to use the product formula and taylor series of $\xi$ to get the result?

Comment: You can look at the details in the book you cited in your other question: Keving Broughan: Equivalents of Riemann Hypothesis I (p. 35).

Comment: @Gary I am sorry. I could not follow from there. Please write as an answer. Please.

Comment: Is the value of the sum also part of the equivalence relation?

Comment: @user no it is not. I have provided it for clarity.

Comment: @user Can you please provide a proof of the converse part.

Comment: @user I have edited my question and removed the value of the sum.

Comment: @Gary Please write as an answer. I will be obliged to give a check mark. Please. Or give me a reference for its proof.

Comment: @user Please reply. Please answer.

Comment: @Gary Please reply. I won't be able to sleep. Please.

Comment: @user Please reply. I won't be able to sleep.

Comment: @Gary I don't see how your comment helps. Look instead at https://urlz.fr/fbLT for $a$ real and $t >1$.

Comment: @reuns Can you please prove the converse?

Comment: @reuns Please give me a reference for the proof of this equivalence.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns I have asked a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $1/2<\sigma<1, t \ne 0, \rho=\sigma+it$ we have $|\rho|^2=\sigma^2+t^2>(1-\sigma)^2+t^2=|1-\rho|^2$ so $\frac{2\sigma -1}{|\rho|^2} < \frac{2\sigma -1}{|1-\rho|^2}$ (since $2\sigma-1>0$) and by rearranging a little we get:

$\frac{2\sigma}{|\rho|^2} +\frac{2(1-\sigma)}{|1-\rho|^2}< \frac{1}{|\rho|^2}+\frac{1}{|1-\rho|^2}$

But now the expression above is symmetric in $\sigma, 1-\sigma$ so by interchanging them the inequality holds for $\sigma < 1/2$ too

Assume $\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}=   \sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}$ and note that both sides are absolutely convergent hence we can regroup at will.

In particular, we rearrange the terms so we group $\rho, 1-\rho, \bar \rho, 1-\bar \rho$ together. If $\Re \rho =1/2$ this grouping has only two terms and appears twice (once for $\rho$ and once for $1-\rho$) while the sum is $\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}=\frac{1}{|1-\rho|^2}$ so the corresponding terms on RHS are equal.

If RH is false there is $\rho=\sigma+it, \sigma \ne 1/2, t > 0$ and the grouping above has $4$ terms each appearing twice (this time for $\rho, 1-\bar \rho$) with sum $\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}+\frac{1}{\bar \rho(1-\bar \rho)}= \frac{2\sigma}{|\rho|^2} +\frac{2(1-\sigma)}{|1-\rho|^2}$ However in this case the corresponding terms on RHS are $\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}+\frac{1}{|1-\rho|^2}$ and by the result in the beginning we get a strict inequality.

Since by the grouping above we showed that LHS is a sum of positive terms, some equal with the corresponding ones on RHs and some strictly less we get the contradiction $\sum_\rho\frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)} <  \sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho|^2}$ so our supposition that RH is false cannot hold. Done!

Comment: Thanks a ton. Can you please provide a reference for this equivalence. It would be very helpful.

Comment: I just proved it on the spot as it is fairly easy to do so have no idea about references

Comment: I am sorry. But I could not follow your answer. After "in particular we rearrange the terms..."

Comment: do you know what an absolutely convergent series is and what properties it has?

Comment: Yes I know. If a series is absolutely convergent then we can rearrange the terms as we please.

Comment: "If RH is false..." I could not understand after this line.

Comment: do you know the symmetries of the zeroes of RZ? (in other words if $\rho$ is a zero, then which numbers are also zeroes?)

Comment: If $\rho$ is a zero then $1-\rho$, $\bar{\rho}$ and $1-\bar{\rho}$ are the zeros.

Comment: Are you there?.

Comment: correct but those $4$ are distinct only when $\Re \rho \ne 1/2$ as otherwise $1-\rho=\bar \rho$; now LHS is a sum on zeroes so for each $\rho$ we have a few terms associated with it corresponding to those roots above; in the RH false case when we do have groups of four, we have four sums per group and two are equal in pairs